# How do I add singular closing div before a element in html '</div>'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dom

I'm generating a series of columns (HTML templates) that are generated in PHP.

The *grid system* is materializecss, which is Material Design.

What I want to do is to add another row `s12`, which is a HTML template, that takes up the entire row beneath the selected `div`, but first I need a close off the row which the selected column resides in, via `</div>`.

I tried it via `innerHTML` and `insertAfter()` but no luck.

```html
<div class='container'>
   <div class='row' >
      <div class='col s6' data-index-value='2'> <!-- This column is dynamically added-->
         <div class="holder-for-blah">
            <p>Blah</p>
            <button id='clicky'>Click to more information about</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

```
// My attempts 
let htmlString = "<div><p>More information section</p></div>";
newDiv = document.createElement('div');
newDiv.innerHTML = htmlString;
newDiv.innerHTML = "</div>" + htmlString
// result is undefined


$( "</div>" + newDiv ).insertAfter( "[data-index-value='2']" ) );
// after a successful response, the new html is simple not added to the DOM


//and even, adding the closing div first and then the element
$( "</div>").insertAfter(  "[data-index-value='2']"  ) );
$( newDiv ).insertAfter( $(  "[data-index-value='2']" );
```

I have already tried getting the `innerHTML` and `insertAfter`.

UPDATED EDIT WITH IMAGES:

Initial grid (fine)
[Starting grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDF7k.png)

When the user clicks on the last column 
It displays fine,
[Last column selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6eUe.png)

The reason why I trying to 'close off the row' is because of this issue.
[When the first or second column is clicked, it gets messed up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHo0h.png)

Comment: why would you want to add a closing div like that - it would mean you would have an extra closing div and therefore most likely break your layout (or at the very least be invalid).  If you just want to put the string after the div, then use `$(newDiv).after(htmlString)`

Comment: This is not how jQuery element creation works to begin with. You can not do stuff like `$( "</div>")` - you can only create _elements_, not individual opening or closing _tags_.

Comment: @Pete .  I'm not trying to add a single string <p>More information section</p> that's only a placeholder of what I want to, what I want to do is to add a new row that takes up the 12 columns underneath the pre-existing row that contains both of the 6 columns

Comment: @04FS Thanks for your advice, Those were just my attempts to resolve

Comment: _“what I want to do is to add a new row that takes up the 12 columns underneath the pre-existing row that contains both of the 6 columns”_ - then append one such element after the element, and done. This really doesn’t need messing around with opening and closing tags separately anywhere.

Comment: So use `$('[data-index-value="2"]').after(newRowHtml)` - don't see where the need for a closing div tag comes in.  Or if you want to use insert after: `$(newRowHtml).insertAfter($('[data-index-value="2"'))`

Comment: Thanks @Pete The thing that is screwing me over is when the button within the 1st column of the row is clicked and new row is created but it pushes the 2nd column completely underneath the newly generated row. I'll work on the .after() and get back to you

Comment: @04FS Based on my knowledge on Bootstrap I was thinking that you must 'close off' first row, before creating a new row, thanks I'll work on this, and get back to you.

Comment: I have updated my initial question, thanks for your help

Comment: Well you can just as easily add another `<div class='row' >` around the whole thing, and then insert it after the existing one. If `data-index-value='2'` is the only thing that makes the right position in the document identifiable, then you can use `.parent()` or `.parents(…)` first to move one level up from there.